# Make page urls correspond to their structure

Tags: url, structure, routes

I set up a page entry type under Structures, and because this is for generic pages, I want it to be arbitrarily nestable. From the structure page, this is easy to set up; however, I want the urls for those entries to correspond to the structure hierarchy - i.e. a root level page with a slug of `page_title` has a corresponding url, but its child page with a slug of `I-am-a-child-page` would have a url of `page_tile/I-am-a-child-page`. This formate should continue for arbitrary levels of nested pages.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: `{parent.uri}/{slug}` is the simplest way to do this. This is basically like a recursive function: Top level pages habe no parent, so their URL is just the slug. Second level pages have a parent with a simple slug as their URI, they get something like `parent-slug/child-slug`. Every subsequent level appends their own slug as a new part to the URI.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there should be an easier way, I just couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 1):

In my page structure entry type I put in a custom URI Format:

`{{ object.getAncestors().all() | map(page => page.slug) | push(slug) | join('/') }}`

If you want help understanding the meaning of that, just ask! If anyone else has a simpler / more readable way to do that, I'm all ears.

Comment: I think you're basically replicating what `{parent.uri}/{slug}` would achieve! These "object templates" fail silently, so if the Entry is at the root, it'll just output nothing. 